# How can I make my application run faster

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I'm building a windows forms application, and I'm processing a huge database, so I have to use many loops to work with my tables.
I'm using C# language, the problem is when the program process data the application lag during the processing and the time require to process my data is not acceptable.

Comment: So you can use Background Workers (Background Threads) to do the processing in order to leave your UI intact. If you are using a Web Server, then you may want to defer your heavy data processing to a service and communicate from the webserver to the process via signalR or some message bus.

Comment: do your time-consuming processing in a separate thread (a thread different from the UI thread). have a look at the async await pattern.

Comment: You have already got 3 close votes for this post because it is too broad a question, provide some more detail else it's bye bye.

Comment: I just want to find a professional way to process my data, also I'm not looking for theories.thank you for your polite response ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well if you are using C# language,
First to prevent the lag issue; use a Task:

```
Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
              //put your code here  
            });
```

and for loops you can use Parallel class it has for and foreach.
if you need to modify something in the GUI you can use the following code:

```
this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                                {
                                  //your code
                                });
```

and there are other ways by creating threads or backgroud workers...

Comment: Thank you I tried the Task.Factory and it works pretty fine now no more lag , I will try the Parallel class to see the result

Comment: Basically the parallel class using for or foreach creates a task for element then wait them at the end, so the class will accelerate you processing but it will make your program consume more resources (CPU).

Answer (score 1):

Try to process your Data in Sql server using stored procedure, views.
Try to use multithreading.
get your data filterd and paged from data base.
Optimize your tables using indexes.

Comment: Well, for me using a stored procedure is not a professional way to solve this problem, because if you are using an architecture such as Three-tier architecture the stored proc will make a confusing between data tier and logic tier

Comment: Using stored procures to enhance/optimize data operations is a valid approach. But your question was not clear enough to know it it's valid for your use case.