# Is there any way I can make this C# code faster?

Tags: c#, performance, x12

I am reading in a large file X12 and parsing the information within. I have two bottleneck functions that I can't seem to work around. read_line() and get_element() Is there any way I could make these two functions faster? The main bottleneck in the get_element function seems to be the Substring method.

```
    public String get_element(int element_number) {
        int count = 0;
        int start_index = 0;
        int end_index = 0;
        int current_index = 0;

        while (count < element_number && current_index != -1) {
            current_index = line_text.IndexOf(x12_reader.element_delimiter, start_index);
            start_index = current_index + 1;
            count++;
        }

        if (current_index != -1) {
            end_index = line_text.IndexOf(x12_reader.element_delimiter, start_index);
            if (end_index == -1) end_index = line_text.Length;
            return line_text.Substring(start_index, end_index - start_index);
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }

    private String read_line() {
        string_builder.Clear();
        int n;
        while ((n = stream_reader.Read()) != -1) {
            if (n == line_terminator) return string_builder.ToString();
            string_builder.Append((char)n);
        }
        return string_builder.ToString();
    }
```

I am reading x12 data. Here is an example of what it looks like. http://examples.x12.org/005010X221/dollars-and-data-sent-together/

Comment: Use a Performance Profiler (E.g. [this](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/) or [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/)).

Comment: Can you give an example of the data that you are parsing? as well as what you are trying to do?

Comment: Do you really think that your bottleneck is in this code not somewhere else? Btw.: I cant see where either `get_element` or `read_line` is used.

Comment: There are library functions that read a text file by line -- writing your own is probably slower.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make my application run faster](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36497334/how-can-i-make-my-application-run-faster)

Comment: Uwe - I have used a profiler. That is how I know these are the problem areas. I know that the Substring Method is a bottleneck but I don't know what I can do to make it faster, and the read_line() function is called millions of times.

Comment: You need to show the call of `get_element`, too.

Comment: If you are calling get_element sequentiallyfor each element number then you are searching from all of the input string multiple times - you could save the last end_index (out parameter ?) & use that as the start_index for the next element in sequence.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: HimBromBeere - I am only showing the code that is causing the bottlenecks. I can't show everything on here.

Comment: You might find this project useful.  It is an X12 parser on CodePlex:  http://x12parser.codeplex.com/

Comment: The program just doesn't do much.  Except two things: collect a lot of garbage and digging through a large file.  You generate a *lot* of strings, they are not for free.  A simple check is to verify how much time is spent on collections, it is a performance counter.  Testing your program repeatedly on the same file is also *very* misleading, you can't see the cost of reading the file.  Which is very high, the file system cache hides it.  The ultimate way of dealing with a program that takes too long to read a big file is to never wait for it.  A watched pot never boils.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful Except it's already answered here, so there's no point in moving it. Closing because it's on-topic somewhere else isn't a great tactic. If you close a question, close it because it's off-topic here. We see way too many comments like this redirecting questions to Code Review.

Comment: @Mast - That comment was written when none of the answers were written for this question. Please check the timestamp before commenting!

Comment: @Daniel, you just need to implement caching. You are calling `get_element(int)` all over the place, effectively reading the same things again and again. Add a private `Dictionary<int, string> elements` to your `segment` class that maps element indeces to the element content. Now the first thing you do inside `get_element(int)` is to check whether `elements.TryGetValue(element_number, out element_content)` returns `true`. If so return `element_content` immdiately. Otherwise parse it like before, add it to the cache with `elements[element_number] = element_content` and return it.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful The rest of the points still stand.

Answer (score 4):

Since your profiler tells you `get_element` is a bottleneck, and the method itself is coded very efficiently, you need to minimize the number of times this method is called.

Calling `get_element` repeatedly in a loop forces it to performs the same parsing job repeatedly:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i != n ; i++) {
    var element = get_element(i);
    ... // Do something with the element
}
```

You should be able to fix this problem by rewriting `get_element` as `GetElements` returning all elements as a collection, and then taking individual elements from the same collection in a loop:

```
var allElements = GetElements();
for (int i = 0 ; i != n ; i++) {
    var element = allElements[i];
    ... // Do something with the element
}
```

> in most cases I only need one or two elements

In this case you could make a method that retrieves all required indexes at once - for example, by passing [`BitArray`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) of required indexes.

Comment: Thanks dasblinkenlight, but the problem is that in most cases I only need one or two elements. Retrieving all of the elements would only slow things down.

Comment: @Daniel Reducing the number of calls is the strategy that you need to follow, because the method itself is coded pretty efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, second try. Discarding `String.Split` due to performance reasons, something like this should work much faster than your implementation:

```
//DISCLAIMER; typed in my cell phone, not tested. Sure it has bugs but you should get the idea.
public string get_element(int index)
{
     var buffer = new StringBuilder();
     var counter = -1;

     using (var enumerator = text_line.GetEnumerator())
     {
         while (enumerator.MoveNext())
         {
             if (enumerator.Current == x12_reader.element_delimiter)
             {
                 counter++;
             }
             else if (counter == index)
             {
                 buffer.Append(enumerator.Current);
             }
             else if (counter > index)
                 break;
        }
     }

     return buffer.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks InBetween but this ended up being slower than my current method. It appears that building using a Stringbuilder is slower than using SubString

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are doing exactly, but if I'm understanding your code correctly, wouldn't get element be simpler as follows?

```
public string get_Element(int index)
{
    var elements = line_text.Split(new[] { x12_reader.element_delimiter });

    if (index > elements.Length)
        return "";

    return elements[index];
}
```

Comment: This would be simpler but I doubt it would be faster -- this has to parse the entire line on every call.  However, calling split once and then indexing that later (which is probably what he is doing he does not show us all the code) would be much faster I expect.

Comment: @Hogan You are avoiding calls to `Substring` and `IndexOf`. `Split` is pretty optimized so I'm not so sure what would be faster to be honest.

Comment: That is simpler to read but much worse performance.

Comment: @InBetween - your point is valid -- his scanner is horribly written since it uses index of instead of a loop.  He says the slow down is in sub-string according to the profiler -- so that is strange.  We really need to see the whole program or profiler output.